# How to call a jquery event in javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, methods

I am really new to javascript objects.

Here is my code:

```
(function(){
var homenavmenu = {
    nav:$('.navMenuButton'),
    target:$(this).attr('href'),
    test:function(){
        // alert(homenavmenu.target)
        homenavmenu.nav.click(function(){
            alert(1);
            return false;
        })
    }
}

homenavmenu.test();
})()
```

Why doesn't it work? It won't `alert(1);`

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="navMenu">
  <a href="../market" class="navMenuButton" id="mo">market</a>
  <a href="../unit" class="navMenuButton" id="unit">my</a>
</div>
```

Comment: show you html as well man,? your function does shows alert without `homenavmenu...`.

Comment: it should be fine  http://jsfiddle.net/aWgqk/

Comment: You're missing your `$` at the front of your dom ready method :)

Comment: no after i add the $ sign the firebug shows a error says $(function(){}()is not a function

Comment: `$(function() {
 /* code here */
});`

Comment: that is what i did. isn't it?

Comment: You had `( )` at the end, as if trying to invoke it. Leave that off and it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/5JmdD/3/

PLease check your html again, demo is working with what you need.

Behavior: click on the button and you will get alert.

Hope this helps `:)`

**code**

```
$(function(){
var homenavmenu = {
    nav:$('.navMenuButton'),
    target:$(this).attr('href'),
    test:function(){
        // alert(homenavmenu.target)
       homenavmenu.nav.click(function(){
            alert(1);
            return false;
        })
    }
}

homenavmenu.test();
})()​
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="hulk" class="navMenuButton" />​
```

Comment: with my html its not working,after click the <a> the page reload to the href, still won't alert

Comment: @chenliang no worries man `:)` flick you html or better yet chuck it in jsfiddle I will take a look,

Comment: @chenliang -- here you go http://jsfiddle.net/JRwY2/3/ -- two things to note. When using jsFiddle you *must* load the library (dropdown menu, left) of jQuery to run the jQuery library. `$` is not a function, unless you have the jQuery library installed (or another library using the `$`). Also, you need to use `(function($){` to begin and `})(jQuery)` to end if you wish to protect your function.

Comment: @Tats_innit--thanx man， really appreciate your help. it work in jsfiddle but not work on local. i will keep on looking the error ,but again thank you so much

Comment: @chenliang Glad I can help man! http://jsfiddle.net/rwJW9/ `:))` hmm check something must be wrong in th HTML bruv

Comment: @chenliang add `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` to the page you are using this function on. Ensure that the above script has been added to the page **before** you attempt to invoke that function, as well.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Indeed `:)` heh - innit Sire :P

Comment: @chenliang **working here** `:)` http://jsfiddle.net/JRwY2/8/ you must be missing Javascript librbary add this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>‌​`

Comment: but i did add the<script type="text/javascript" src='../../js/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script> in <head>

Comment: @ Tats_innit and if you uncomment the first alert(), it works,

Answer (score 0):

ok it seems like you can't use

```
nav:$('.navMenuButton'),
```

should use

```
nav:'.navMenuButton',
```

invoke as

```
$(homenavmenu.nav).click(function(){
   alert(1)
})
```

this work for me,but i don't know why it worked in the example above.